# A word to make something bad sound good

Tags: single-word-requests

Lets say we are talking about a book about teens that drink. In the book, the teens have fun and nothing bad ever happens. It's disguising it as a good thing, it's supporting it and it's making it sound good.

What word would you use to describe what the book is doing to teen drinking?

Comment: Very, very nice question.

Comment: teenagers often drink and have fun without anything bad happening. it doesn't sound like the book is disguising anything - just telling a story about something that happens in real life every day. unless the book actively supports the behavior or makes it sound good (through an all-knowing narrator or something), i don't think this question applies. a book that depicts teens who drink without negative consequences doesn't necessarily *support* the behavior.

Comment: _romanticising_ hasn't been mentioned yet .. deal with or describe in an idealized or unrealistic fashion; make (something) seem better or more appealing than it really is

Comment: See the terminology used in the answers to this question: [Positive euphemisms for desert?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52287/positive-euphemisms-for-desert). Try "positive connotation".

Comment: @wim -- Please make that an answer. *Romanticize* is exactly what the OP is shooting for. From Google (as in literally from Google; from that little box they often pop up if you google a single word): `Romanticize: deal with or describe in an idealized or unrealistic fashion; make (something) seem better or more appealing than it really is.`

Comment: I've heard `legitimize` used in this context.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The term *[glorify](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/glorify)* means

> Describe or represent as admirable, especially unjustifiably or undeservedly:
>   *a football video glorifying violence* [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Answer (score 63):

**Sugarcoating** is one possibility -- if the book is "sugar-coating" teenage drinking, it is taking something negative and adding a superficial positive sheen.  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sugarcoat):

> to talk about or describe (something) in a way that makes it seem more pleasant or acceptable than it is

**Glamorizing** is another -- to glamorize is to take something that is neutral, or maybe negative, and imbue it with more of a glamorous aspect than it might deserve.  [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/glamorize):

> Make (something) seem glamorous or desirable, especially spuriously so

I think either of the above would convey your meaning in this context.

Comment: Glamorizing is a good, straight-forward term for the concept.  Perhaps not as "catchy" as one would like.

Comment: Glamorize is what come closest in my world, closely followed by glorify.

Answer (score 15):

Here are some possibilities:

- justifying
- excusing
- promoting
- rationalizing
- papering over
- glossing over
- condoning
- whitewashing

I think *whitewashing* is probably the best choice.

Comment: I agree with *whitewashing*, *rationalizing*, and *glossing over*, but they are used in slightly different ways. Your answer would be improved by providing some explanation and links to definitions.

Comment: Really like whitewashing, even if it doesn't apply in all usages.  Physically, it is "making something appear better" by applying a coat of whitewash.  Note that there's not an implication that the item being whitewashed is better, but there is an implication that it appears to be better afterwards.  In your example, the book attempts to whitewash teen drinking.

Comment: Trivialising could possibly be used as well.

Comment: I agree with the comment of Nigel Ellis above: 'Trivialising' is the first that popped to my mind (wanted to upvote his comment but can't due to insufficient reputation).

Comment: This answer has two or three excellent terms but there are no links, explanations, or definitions. Such a shame.

Answer (score 8):

**Euphemism**: A mild or pleasant word or phrase that is used instead of one that is unpleasant or offensive. (from ["Merriam Webster"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism/))

Comment: "Euphemism" doesn't really fit with what OP is looking for, although one of its derivatives does: Euphemize

Answer (score 3):

Destigmatize might be the word you are looking for. Opposite of stigmatize. "destigmatize violence" returns about 700 results in Google.

> destigmatize: to remove associations of shame or disgrace from
>   [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/destigmatize)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the upvoted answers (I often hear “glorify” used this way in AmE, possibly due to the [Hays Code](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hays%20code%22%20glorify)), I’d like to add the concepts of **sympathetic** portrayal and **sentimentalization.**

---

You could say that the book cast underage drinking in a **sympathetic** light or that the book offered a **sympathetic** portrayal of teenage alcohol consumption.

> **sym·pa·thet·ic** 
> *adjective*
>
> : having or showing support for or approval of something
>
> : having pleasant or appealing qualities : causing feelings of sympathy
>
> [. . .]
>
> 5. a :  showing empathy
>
>    b :  arousing sympathy or compassion 
>    *a sympathetic role in the play*
>
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster definition of “sympathetic”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sympathetic)</sub>

---

“Sentimentalization” is not particularly apt for your specific case, but might be useful to others with a similar question.

> **sentimentalize**
> *[transitive, intransitive]*
>  sentimentalize (something)
>  *(disapproving)*
>
> to present something in an emotional way, emphasizing its good aspects and not mentioning its bad aspects
>
> *Jackie was careful not to sentimentalize country life.*
>
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “sentimentalize” from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sentimentalize)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

bib's suggestion of *glorify*, and McGarnagle's *glamourise* are obviously superb.

Below are a few others words that - at least in one of their meanings - specifically convey *undeserved or excessive* praise.  All definitions/links from http://www.oxforddictionaries.com.  Example sentences mine....

- [aggrandise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aggrandize?q=aggrandise): *enhance the reputation of (someone) beyond what is justified by the facts* - "the book aggrandised the reckless, wanton behaviour"
- [dignifies](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dignify?q=dignifies):  *Give an impressive name to (someone or something unworthy of it)* - "the book dignifies drunkenness as some manifestation of personal freedoms"
- [idealise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dignify?q=dignifies): *Regard or represent as perfect or better than in reality*

And another that isn't necessarily unwarranted praise, but would imply that pretty clearly if describing such a book:

- poeticise: *to give a poetic quality to*

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fancy word for it, I suggest ***edulcorate***.

> **Edulcorate:** Make (something) more acceptable or palatable

> Example: The traditional folk song is today often edulcorated by unwarranted accompaniments.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/edulcorate)]

Comment: I didn't think this would be in the mainstream dictionaries, before I checked. But if you'd added a quote from Lexico say (linked and attributed), I'd have been quite prepared to upvote.

Comment: Mr. Edwin Ashworth: Thank you. You may upvote now. :)

Comment: But I had to do the research myself. I'll think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Talking it up.
Dressing it up.
Putting it in a good light.

Comment: Please give a rationale for why those phrases work.

Answer (score 0):

not mentioned yet:

- *exalting*
- *extenuating*
- *palliating*

neutral:

- *describing*
- *portraying*
- *depicting*

neologisms and creative solutions:

- *innocenting*
- *naivizing / naivicing / naivising, naiving*
- *anglizing / anglising / anglicing* – antonym to *demonizing*, not to be confused with *anglicizing*)
- *depuritanizing* or repurposed *purifying*
- *evangelizing* – if it’s close to *promoting*
- *subliming* – ditto
- *madmenning* > *madboying, madkidding, madyouthing* – pop culture reference, to expire soon
- *deconsequencing, asequencing, nonsequencing …* – leaving out consequences
- *roseglassing* – as in *through rose-colored glasses*
- *unicorning, rainbowing* – similar to *sugar-coating*
- *stonering* – as in stoner movies
- *targetdemographicing*
- *politicianizing* – make sound or appear politically correct
- *spindoctoring* or repurposed *spinning* or *doctoring*
- *truthbending*
- *ebaying, fleamarketing*

Answer (score -6):

I don't believe a single word would capture what you are describing. Languages don't usually work that way. It is neither necessary nor desirable to try to condense every concept into a single term. From what you say, the book is doing nothing to teen drinking. It simply omits any description of the dangers.

Comment: In the future, if you don't think that there's an answer that satisfies a question, at least wait long enough to see if others can find an answer before declaring it improbable or impossible, please.